# Range of $g(x)=\cot^{-1}\log_{1/2}(x^4-2x^2+3)$

Tags: functions

Theoretically, we know that the range and domain of $f(x)=\cot^{-1}x$ is $(-\infty,\infty)$ and $(0,\pi)$, respectively. Its plot is a smooth continuous function.

Strangely, I find that Wolfram Mathematica plots it as an odd
discontinuous (at $x=0$) function in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$!

**Question 1:** Have you encountered this?

In this regard, the range of $$g(x)=\cot^{-1} \log_{1/2}(x^4-2x^2+3).......(1)$$
could be found interesting. This is an even function in the domain $(-\infty,\infty).$
We get $$g'(x)=\frac{-1}{1+[\log_{1/2}(x^4-2x^2+3)]^2}\frac{(4x^3-4x)}{x^4-2x^2+3} $$
$g'(x)=0$ gives stationary points as $x=0,\pm 1.$
$g(0)=\cot^{-1}\log_{1/2} 3\approx 2.57, g(\pm 1) = \cot^{-1} \log_{1/2}2=\cot^{-1} (-1)=3\pi/4\approx 2.35.$ The limiting values of $g(\pm \infty)\to \cot^{-1}\log_{1/2} (\infty)\to \cot^{-1} (-\infty)\to \pi.$
Consequently, the range of $g(x)$ is $$[3\pi/4,\pi).......(2)$$

**Question 2:** Is the obtained range correct and what could be other ways of finding it.

**Edit** The news itself that Mathematica doesn't treat $\cot^{-1}x$ properly is valuable and sufficient one may apply personal adhoc corrections.
By writing in Mathematica adhoc $\cot^{-1}x=\pi-\cot^{-1}|x|$ or $\cot^{-1}x=\pi/2-\tan^{-1} x$ as suggested by @heropup, we find the plot $g(x) (1)$ below:
[image]

In this regard, the fig plotted by @Kurt G is correct in shape by chance as $g(x)$ is an even function but the numbers on $y$-axis are not correct there.

Comment: Doesn't look correct. [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+arccot%28+log%28x%5E4-2x%5E2%2B3%29%2Flog%281%2F2%29+%29) is my favourite way of finding it.

Comment: Don't you get $[3\pi/4,\pi)$

Comment: You mentioned Wolfram Alpha and I sent you a link that plots that function. Look at the graph. BTW: what is the context that makes this function worthwhile to study?

Comment: Mathematica chose a convention different than the most common one for the inverse of $\cot$. A lot of programming language have different definitions for some functions and one should be always careful with that.

Comment: Sorry @Kurt G, your Fig. is correct only  shapewise as the function happens to be even, the numbers on $y$ axis are incorrect. you may see my Edit.

Comment: Kurt's graph seems to be incorrect numerically as the range of $g(x)$ is $[3\pi/4,\pi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could divide it into some easier parts.   let's think about this $f(x)=x^4-2x^2+3=(x^2-1)^2+2 \to R_f=[2,+\infty)$ then you can take $\log$ so $$g(x)=\log_{\frac 12}f(x)=-\log_2 f(x)\\2\le f(x)< \infty\\1\le \log_2 f(x)<\infty\\ \to \\ -\infty<\log_{\frac 12}f(x) \le -1$$  then apply $cot^{-1}$
You can also use substitution $u=(x^2-1)^2+2$ with $2\le u <\infty$ and find $$cot^{-1}(-\log_2 u)$$ and finally $$A=-\log_2 u \to \\ -\infty<A \le -1\\\frac{3\pi}{4}\le \cot^{-1}(A) <\pi$$ [image]

Comment: What is your final answer?

Comment: @ZAhmed: I complete the answer

Comment: Thank you, you may see my Edit and comment more,

Answer (score 3):

*Mathematica* uses the range $\cot^{-1} x \in (-\pi/2, 0) \cup (0, \pi/2)$ for real-valued $x$.  It does this for reasons related to the choice of branch of the complex-valued function.  It's not ideal in cases where we want a continuous function, but one way to work around this is to employ the relationship
$$\cot^{-1} x = \frac{\pi}{2} - \tan^{-1} x, \quad x \in \mathbb R.$$
This yields the desired domain and range for your function.